# How to blur an image when someone mouse over it and show some text?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a box with an image inside. When a user hover on the box it should be blurred and show some text on the blurred area.

[image]

When a user hover on this box it should be like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share you code on [JSFIDDLE](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that I can get it easily.

I don't know about your code but you can blur any image by css :

```
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
```

Comment: i just know basic html and css. see this http://codepen.io/ whenwver you mouseover on this its blurs and shows some text. it should work like this..its showing black color blur background but i want just normal background

Comment: Then what you want? Share the code I will do my best for you :)

Comment: thanx @mhk just see the codepen website there are 6 box and some images there when you mouse over on this it blurs and shows some text i want this effect.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6v8Tb/15/ check it out it may help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6v8Tb/16/ check with transition.

Comment: exactly i want this.how can i reduce the blur amount an how to add multiple boxes or image?

Comment: Yes you can ! -webkit-filter: blur(1px);  filter: blur(1px);